# How to close infobox on zoom out

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a map with some markers and markerclusters and it's working fine. I added InfoBoxes to them and they work but the problem is, when I zoom out and an InfoBox is open, the marker will disappear (and get aded to the markercluster) and the box will stay there, open with no marker below.

I could work with the simple solution of having all infoboxes close on zoom change but I can't even achieve that. The problem I have is that inside my listener I can't access my markers for some reason. Here is my code:

```
var infoList = [];

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      ...
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
        mapOptions);
    var imageUrl = 'pin.png';
    var markers = []; 
    var markerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(imageUrl, new google.maps.Size(51, 71));

    for (var i = 0; i < data.photos.length; i++) { 
        var dataPhoto = data.photos[i];
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dataPhoto.latitude, dataPhoto.longitude);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            icon: markerImage,
            title: dataPhoto.photo_title
        });
        boxText = document.createElement("div"),

        infoboxOptions = {
            alignBottom:true,
            content: boxText,
            disableAutoPan: false,
            maxWidth: 0,
            pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-60, -70),
            zIndex: null,
            boxStyle: { 
              width: "280px"
             },
            closeBoxMargin: "12px 4px 2px 2px",
            closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif",
            infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1),
            isHidden: false,
            pane: "floatPane",
            enableEventPropagation: false
        };

        markers.push(marker);

        markers[i].infobox = new InfoBox(infoboxOptions);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                markers[i].infobox.open(map, this);
                map.panTo(latLng);
            }
        })(marker, i));

    }

    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function(markers){
        /*Here markers is undefined*/
        if (! markers.length) { return; }
        for (i in markers) {
           markers[i].infoBox.close();
        }

    });
}
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new "markers" variable inside the zoom_changed listener.  Remove "markers" from the arguments list:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function(){
    if (! markers.length) { return; }
    for (i in markers) {
       markers[i].infobox.close();
    }
});
```

Your code is not consistent, the property of marker that you are creating is:

```
markers[i].infobox = new InfoBox(infoboxOptions);
```

I changed the above (should have been obvious to you in the debugger).

Comment: also that markers = [] wasn't on my original code, it slipped on the copy paste somehow. I removed it from the original question.

Comment: There is a typo infoBox vs. infobox.

Comment: Oh boy, you are so very right, how did I not see that! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, if you want to close all info window in you map at zoom out or zoom in then you can use this code. It will Help you.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
infoWindow.close();
});
```

Comment: That will only work if there is a single infoWindow, called infoWindow. I don't see that defined in the posted code.

Comment: That's not true, If you declare Infowindow object globally, then it will close all opened info windows which are opened with that object.

Comment: I don't have infoWindow objects, I have infoBox wich, afaik, are not the same.